# How to include "redux-file-upload" in my React App

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have found this redux-file-upload called **upload.js**

```
import { FileUpload } from 'redux-file-upload'

<FileUpload

allowedFileTypes={['jpg', 'pdf']}
  data={{ type: 'picture' }}
  dropzoneId="fileUpload"
  url="./uploads/"
>
  <button>
    Click or drag here
  </button>
</FileUpload>
```

and I want to use it in React. this file is called **Tab5.js** :

```
import React from 'react';
import './../css/bootstrap.css';
import './../css/styles.css';
import Modale from './modalProces';


class Tab5 extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <FileUpload />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
 export default Tab5;
```

but whenever I run it, Tab5 doesn't show up. 
**I already installed:**
-npm install --save redux
-npm install --save react-redux
-npm install --save-dev redux-devtools
-npm install --save redux-file-upload
Am I missing any imports? Am I doing the whole thing wrong?
 
I'm not used to coding in React, but I'm forced to do this part.
I just need the file upload to work, where it uploads a file into the **uploads** folder. 
Please Help me.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand of your question, you are either using the **upload.js** file as an example and trying to implement FileUpload in **Tab5.js** or you want to use **upload.js** as a component in **Tab5.js**. I will attempt to address both.
The documentation for `redux-file-upload` library can be found [here](https://github.com/blueberryapps/redux-file-upload).

### If you are using upload.js as a component

You have setup the file upload component in **upload.js** but the file does not export anything, you are also missing the whole class declaration and `render()` function like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FileUpload } from 'redux-file-upload'
//any other imports you need

export class Upload extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            <FileUpload
                allowedFileTypes={['jpg', 'pdf']}
                data={{ type: 'picture' }}
                dropzoneId="fileUpload"
                url="./uploads/"
                >
                <button>
                    Click or drag here
                </button>
            </FileUpload>
        )
    }
}
```

And then in **Tab5.js** you will import and use Upload as a component.

```
import React from 'react';
import './../css/bootstrap.css';
import './../css/styles.css';
import Modale from './modalProces';
import Upload from './upload'; //import the upload.js file


class Tab5 extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <Upload />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Tab5;
```

### If you are using upload.js as an example

`dropzoneId` and `url` are required properties. So **Tab5.js** would look like something like this at the least (you will probably want to add in other options as well):

```
import React from 'react';
import { FileUpload } from 'redux-file-upload'; //add in the redux-file-upload import
import './../css/bootstrap.css';
import './../css/styles.css';
import Modale from './modalProces';


class Tab5 extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <div>
                <FileUpload 
                    dropzoneId="fileUpload"
                    url="./uploads/"
                >
                    <button>
                        Click or drag here
                    </button>
                </FileUpload>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Tab5;
```